# She said, "Never trust a man whose eyes are so close together!"

Tags: modifiers

She said, "Never trust a man whose eyes are so close together!"

It means the distance between eyes are short.

Does “together” modify “close”?

Comment: Partial answer: It looks like yes, "together" modifies "close". "Close together" = "close to each other/one another", so in whatever way "to each other" modifies "close" (or doesn't), "together" does the same thing. Someone else might know how to describe what "to each other" does.

Comment: @gotube I’m quite surprised that an adverb modifies an adjective, located after the adjectives.

Comment: Also, "close together" is idiomatic, rather than structural, so don't be *that* surprised :)

Answer (score 2):

"Close together" is an idiomatic expression, as is its opposite, "far apart". From a practical perspective, they have to be learned as special expressions.

If anything, though, I would say that "close" is better described as modifying "together"; it is the degree to which they are together.
Both expressions can be made comparative: *Do you want to sit closer together or farther apart?* While a distance cannot be specified with "together", it can with "apart": *They are 3 meters apart*. And note that the distance can be omitted entirely (*They are apart*), while "apart" cannot (**They are 3 meters*), suggesting that *3 meters* modifies *apart*. It seems reasonable, then, to conclude that *far* also modifies *apart*, and *close* modifies *together*.